# Even after the page is zoomed in and reloaded the window height and document height are same. The vertical scrollbar is visible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On the basis of vertical scrollbar the footer logo is hide/shown. But even when the vertical scrollbar is visible, the height of window and document are same. What might be the case?

`<!DOCTYPE html>` 
is already in the page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9kbs.png)

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @AlekseyDubinskiy The document with a vertical scrollbar is reloaded and the document and window height are equal.

Comment: Are we talking about browser zoom or translate scale or css zoom property?
How did you get these values?
https://ibb.co/MkkmyNw

Comment: @AlekseyDubinskiy I figured out some css ran after the JS code ran. Thank you for your help.